# Submit a form using a Class/method as the action

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, class, pdo

In an attempt to learn PDO I am using the sakila database to set up prepared inserts, selects, updates etc along with using a PDO connection in a class. I am using php and WAMP

What I am doing: I am trying to submit a form using the class and a method as the action. I also need to reference the class/method in the Ajax URL. Getting data from the class method to display is easy. I do not know how to use it with forms.

I have read/watched tons of tutorials but all reference the data coming into the class, but never how it got there from the form.

I know that to use a class in a page you must do it like this

```
$class=New Class();
$class->method();
```

How do you translate that to a form action and a URL in ajax?

```
<form action="CLASS/METHOD" method="POST" id="addmail">

$.ajax({
type: "POST",
    url: "CLASS/METHOD", 
    data: data,
```

Ive no problem with jquery, it is submitting the correct form inputs in an alert after serialization. I am just lost on this one action that I cant find the answer to any wheres.

Thank you for your consideration, I hope I presented this clearly

EDIT if this cannot be done with a class, could you just reference a function as in

```
action "<?php insert();?>"
```

Comment: You have to have some base controller or router that translates the part of url from `http://mydomain.com/<class>/<method>/<params>` into a call `$Class->method($params);`. Every MVC framework has it's own router and it's own controller handler, so to tell You how to achieve this is just a way of preference...

Comment: I have used codeigniter in the past, but this is straight PHP.

Comment: So You have no MVC structure? I guess You have some when needing to call `$class->method();` from a view/template... If nothing then in Your `index.php` watch for URL like mentioned in comment above and if present (e.g. `/user/create/`) just instantiate `new User` and call it's method `create()`. Nothing more trivial I could suggest. Better if You place that in some `routes.php` script where You can handle more of these actions...

Comment: I can figure that out, thanks. Several routes tuts around. Would hate to think I am wasting my time with class's :) Make that as an answer and we can close this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as opposed in my comments, I'd go this way:

In Your index.php watch for URL like mentioned in comment above and if present (e.g. `/user/create/`) just instantiate `new User` and call it's method `create()`. Nothing more trivial I could suggest. Better if You place that in some `routes.php` script where You can handle more of these actions...

PS: now I'm not sure why suggest this in answer when You decided to forget about classes and go with procedural PHP...

My opinion: Go with OO PHP, procedural PHP is relic.

Comment: I cant use the OOP or php address for a function in the ajax part. So basically neither is useful to me. Of course I could just forget the Ajax part as well and use a straight php file. I can use oop when it doesnt require a form to be used. I just wanted to give you credit for answering in the first place

Answer (score 0):

I got rid of the class and just went with functions. Much easier. Thanks shadyyyx. If you still want add your answer and I will try to mark it accepted